# How can I make an aggregate foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a situation where there are `product`, `option`, `option_value` and `product_option_value` tables. An option can have multiple values and a product can be mapped to multiple option values. Now I have a third entity, `code`, which maps to a combination of a product and *zero or more* options.

To come up with an example, think t-shirt as the product, with color and size options and red/blue and small/large option values. Now I have this code, "bigblueshirt", that I need to map to the *combination of* product #1 (shirt), option #1 (size) value #1 (large) *and* option #2 (color) value #2 (blue). I could also have "shirt", "blueshirt" and "bigshirt", so they could be null. The code is sort of a triple (or more) of product_id,option_value,option_value,...

Is there any way to represent this in SQL? The only thing I can think of is a code mapping table with a FK to `product.id` and some columns that are FKs to `option_value.id`, either one column per option (manually created) or some deterministic convention like lowest ID first, to prevent duplicates (in any order). Unfortunately I don't think I can enforce a "column type" to match the option. Maybe enforce it with a trigger. This all seems rather kludgy though...

**Update 1:**

I could easily have multiple FKs to the same table (`option_value`), that's my current plan, but that seems ugly. I was wondering if there was another better way to design it so that the product could be associated with multiple option values, given that the `option_values` table includes multiple option types (`option` rows). The requirements would be (OVA1 is option value 1 which relates to option A):

- Zero or one set of option values per product. (P1, OVA1, OVB2, OVC3)
- No duplicate option values in the set. (not: P1, OVA***1***, OVB2, OVA***1***)
- Zero or one option per set. (not: P1, OV***A***1, OV***A***5, OVB2)

Unfortunately I can't change the existing schema, without tons of work--just add new stuff for this mapping. The best thing I can come up with is a table with `product_id` and an arbitrary number of `option_value_id` columns (as many as I expect to need, at least), with a trigger to enforce the requirements. I suppose I could normalize out the option values into a `option_value_set` table, but I think that would just kick the can to another table. If it's possible to do in a clearer or simpler or more explicit way, though, that would be preferable.

Comment: have you used FK's long ? How is this unique from those?

Comment: Yes I have. I'll update to clarify.